# How do you substitute a variable in the "instanceof" function

Tags: java, for-loop, instanceof

I have the following classes in my java project `Wheels`, `Engine`, `Brake` which all implement `CarPart`

Objects created are stored in an `ArrayList<CarPart> parts` variable.

I want to check three things:

1. Does my car have any Wheels?
2. Does my car have any Engine?
3. Does my car have any Brake?

I can write the `hasWheels` function, then write literally the same code again but replace Wheels with `Engine`, then with `Brake`. Its all duplicate code. Is there a way where I can pass a parameter to a function like `doesArrayContain(parts, Wheels)`?

---

```
public boolean hasWheels(ArrayList<CarPart> parts) {

    for (CarPart part : parts) {
        if (part instanceof Wheels)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

Something like this

```
public boolean doesArrayContain(ArrayList<CarPart> parts, Type type) {

    for (CarPart part : parts) {
        if (part instanceof type)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Pass a `Class` object and use its [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method.

Comment: @KevinAnderson What is the Type? This? `doesArrayContain(ArrayList<CarPart> parts, Class type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the instanceOf method which is apart of the class, 'Class'

Also your logic seems to be flawed, you're returning false for when the list does contain. (unless you named it wrong?) So I swapped the return statements.

```
public boolean doesArrayContain(ArrayList<CarPart> parts, Class<? extends CarPart> type) {

    for (CarPart part : parts) {
        if (type.isInstance(part.getClass()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

use it like `doesArrayContain(myList, Wheels.class)`